# How to pull data from server

Tags: android, pull

i need help for implementing a pulling system.

In my app I have a list to display updated data that will be pulled from a server. The list will refresh every 1 minute to update its data. This refresh will continue as long as my app is active. Any suggestion or example will be greater for me to carry out my work. Thanks...

Comment: Can you be more specific? Do you want to connect with a socket? Do you want to make http requests? How much data do you want to send and is it in a particular format? There are a lot of ways to get data from a server.

Comment: @ethan I have managed a HttpPost request to get data from server. But I do not know how to pull data continuously...

Comment: what's wrong with repeatedly making http post requests?

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is, in an async task , download all the data you need from the web-service.
Add those elements in the adapter. Then every minute call this AsyncTask and Invalidate your listView.
Let me know if this works.